# Canvas drawing client side vs pre processed SVG graphics

Tags: javascript, node.js, mobile, canvas, svg

**The background:**

A graphics project I am working on runs great (fast) on a PC, but on many tablets (original iPad here) it draws my Canvas graphics very slow.  Graphics are the bulk of my project, so this is pretty close to unacceptable.

I am considering investigating SVG as the solution but am an SVG noob.  I like the whole scaleable (vector) benefits, **but I am  worried about file size**.  I currently just provide a small amount of data to a client side Canvas drawing fn and let the browser draw the canvas.  This is easy on the server and great for bandwidth, but perhaps too much work for tablet processors.

However, with several hundred SVG ("nodes"??) in my graphic, the amount of text that SVG produces seems - *HUGE*.

**The question:**

I have the time to pre-process all my graphics locally and upload to production if I can figure out how to do it.  If I create the SVG graphic on a local web page (programatically of course - perhaps NodeJS), can I somehow convert the finished graphic to a file (is that what "data uri" is?) and then compress it (gzip)?  I call my graphics via AJAX calls already so no biggie there.

If I do this pre-processing, will the result be less work for the app client?  Will the file size of the (currently imaginary) gzipped SVG be small even for a few hundred drawing items? Does it make sense to you that SVG would be faster given that it would just draw instead of processing a lot of Javascript drawing canvas objects? (I am using KineticJS, its pretty good imo, like I said, *great* on a PC).

Is this doable, or do you think I am barking up the wrong tree to solve the drawing speed issue?  Are there solutions that programatically create / compress SVG already?  As always, thanks kindly.

Comment: It's a bit essential to know *what kind of graphics* you want to produce/pre-process. And please share some code of what you have done so far, if possible also a fiddle.

Comment: Just about every kind of chart - line, pie, bar, etc.  Limited (if any) user interactivity.  SVG's vector approach seems well suited for adapting from PC widescreens (1680x1050) to tablet resolutions.  There's no code to share here yet.

Comment: 1) do you use drawImage, or paths (beginPath, lineTo, ...) to do the drawing ? 2) if using path, do you use patterns to fill() them ? You should expect pretty much the same performances between paths and svg. On mobile devices, it is mainly drawImage that is slow as hell, on ipad4 for instance drawing path is very fast.

Comment: `drawImage()` are generally faster than path drawing on canvas, so you might give that a try. But like Ken said, an example would be great.

Comment: Appreciate everyone's comments.  This question will have to sit on "hold" then until I have some sample code to share.  Its not easy.